# No response after accepting the job offer

Tags: job-offer, human-resources, internship

So I got accepted to an internship from what I can say is my dream company and I am very excited (and also nervous). The interview went well, and the HR staff sent me an offer letter that contains:

- Starting date
- Place, Department, Supervisor Name
- Allowance amount
- Terms and conditions

They also sent me a reply template form and asked for it to be returned within 3 business days. I quickly filled it with acceptance and returned it evening on the same day. It has been 6 days and I haven't heard anything from them ever since. I did ask for a follow up once two days ago but also heard nothing from them.

My university mandatory internship date is coming up close and I will have to prepare 31 days before the internship starting date (quarantine and other stuff). Is the offer being revoked? Can I email again without the risk of losing the position (by being annoying)? Is it acceptable to call the HR person over WhatsApp? Or should I continue the job search?

Or maybe I am just being overly anxious, as this is the first time I am getting accepted for work. Thank you for your assistance!

Edit: Some of you guys suggested me to telephone them. I do not actually have the phone number of the organization, apart from the HR staff that handles me (which from a quick search in LinkedIn, is apparently an intern aswell). I do have the email of the hiring manager, should I email him or is it being too pushy?

Comment: Telephone them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I properly follow-up with a hiring manager, to check on the status of a position?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6018/how-do-i-properly-follow-up-with-a-hiring-manager-to-check-on-the-status-of-a-p)

Comment: What exactly do you want to follow up on? It seems that you got the job offer and know the starting date, so could you please clarify what is it that you're missing?

Comment: @Egor At the very least I need confirmation from them on whether if they received my acceptance letter, and that I should report on duty on my starting date.

Answer (score 6):

If you're in the US, today is [Memorial Day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memorial_Day) (and in the UK, it's a bank holiday).

That means that many people get today off, and when many people get the Monday off, they also take the preceding Friday off, and some people even take the preceding Thursday and Friday off to get a 5-day weekend.

So if a manager/decision-maker is required to approve your paperwork, be assured that they probably haven't even been at the office since last Wednesday or Thursday.

So wait until this Wednesday or Thursday, then follow up. Because that usually means that tomorrow, they'll be playing catch up with all the work they haven't done last Friday and Thursday.

> I will have to prepare 31 days before the internship starting date

This part. I do not fully understand.

If you need a work visa or something else that can not possibly wait, then obviously, contact them sooner rather than later.

Just note that in the US, all of the government offices are going to be closed today also.

> I do not actually have the phone number of the organization

You only need the phone number of a company in order to reach someone. If you have someone's full name, their operator/receptionist/HR or their electronic voice mail system can just forward your phone call to the right person.

Comment: The receptionist can also tell you whether a specific person is on leave if you provide the context. An example phrase to use would be "Hello. I am looking for Mr. Guy in HR. I have signed an acceptance letter from 6 days ago but have not heard anything back. Can you advise if he is on leave or whether another staff can let me know if I am missing anything in the process?"